# Updating values across rows without using a loop in R

Tags: r, loops

I would like to update the values in some rows of a column (sales) using some manipulation:

- There are different number for stock of each vintage in each year.
- "sales" in each year equals to the "stock" of the current year minus 
  what is "remained" from previous years.
- "beta" gives the retirement rate.

I want to calculate sales of vintage 1992 in year 1992 (24.13-16.389=7.7455) and use that value to calculate the sales in year 1993 (10.74=34.871-24.12) and so on. Since the original dataset is huge, the following loop takes for ever. Is there another way (like defining a function) that can do this without using a loop?

```
   for (i in 1992:1993){
  for (j in 1992:1993){
    vy <- vy %>% 
      mutate(retired= ifelse(vintage<year, beta*sales,retired)) %>% 
      group_by(vintage) %>% 
      mutate(cumsum_retired = cumsum(retired)) %>% 
      mutate(remained =sales-cumsum_retired) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      group_by(year) %>% 
      mutate(cumsum_remained =cumsum(remained)) %>% 
      mutate(sales =ifelse(year==vintage & vintage==j & year==i & is.na(sales), stock-lag(cumsum_remained), sales)) %>% 
      mutate(sales =ifelse(sales<0, 0, sales)) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      group_by(vintage) %>% 
      fill(sales)
  }
}
```

Data:

```
vy <- structure(list(year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993), vintage = c(1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1993, 1993, 1993, 1993), beta = c(0, 0, 2e-04, 6e-04, 0, 0, 0, 
2e-04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stock = c(12.996, 12.996, 12.996, 
12.996, 16.392, 16.392, 16.392, 16.392, 24.135, 24.135, 24.135, 
24.135, 34.871, 34.871, 34.871, 34.871), sales = c(12.996, 12.996, 
12.996, 12.996, 3.396, 3.396, 3.396, 3.396, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), retired = c(0, 0, 0.003, 0.008, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 
0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), cumsum_retired = c(0, 0, 0.003, 0.011, 
0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0), remained = c(13, 13, 
13, 13, 3, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), cumsum_remained = c(13, 
13, 13, 13, 16, 16, 16, 16, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `3` = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Expected result:

```
vy<- structure(list(year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 
1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993), vintage = c(1990, 
1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1991, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 
1993, 1993, 1993, 1993), beta = c(0, 0, 2e-04, 6e-04, 0, 0, 0, 
2e-04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), stock = c(12.996, 12.996, 12.996, 
12.996, 16.392, 16.392, 16.392, 16.392, 24.135, 24.135, 24.135, 
24.135, 34.871, 34.871, 34.871, 34.871), sales = c(12.996, 12.996, 
12.996, 12.996, 3.396, 3.396, 3.396, 3.396, NA, NA, 7.7455992, 
7.7455992, NA, NA, NA, 10.7444768), retired = c(0, 0, 0.0025992, 
0.0077976, 0, 0, 0, 0.0006792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), cumsum_retired = c(0, 
0, 0.0025992, 0.0103968, 0, 0, 0, 0.0006792, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0), remained = c(12.996, 12.996, 12.9934008, 12.9856032, 3.396, 
3.396, 3.396, 3.3953208, NA, NA, 7.7455992, 7.7455992, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), cumsum_remained = c(12.996, 12.996, 12.9934008, 12.9856032, 
16.392, 16.392, 16.3894008, 16.380924, NA, NA, 24.135, 24.1265232, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "v", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:3, 4:7, 8:11, 12:15), group_sizes = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), biggest_group_size = 4L, labels = structure(list(
    v = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame", vars = "v", drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: I am having difficulty following the logic of the manipulations. Could you please add some more description at the top of your question, or comments about what the intent of each step is? For instance, what does `v` represent? What is accomplished through the iterations?

Comment: Would the question be addressed using `group_by(year) %>% mutate(sales = stock - lag(stock, default = 0)) %>% ungroup()`?

Comment: I have added an explanation for v and the purpose of iterations.